# Help Interpreting Graph from GLMnet

Tags: r, interpretation, lasso, glmnet, elastic-net

I am going through the Vignette of R GLMnet package. In the plot section, I am confused about the interpretation the author gave[image]

What does he mean by the Lasso performs the best here? How can he say that from the graph? 
Thanks in advance